# Как в консоли OpenServer корректно отобразить кириллицу?

Tags: php, openserver

Как сделать, чтобы в консоли OpenServer корректно отображалась кириллица? Запускаю php файл и в консоли вместо кириллицы - кракозябры:

Иванов Иван                   160     10      1600
Петров Петр                   140     8       1120

> ╨Ш╨▓╨░╨╜╨╛╨▓ ╨Ш╨▓╨░╨╜                   160     10      1600
>
> ╨Я╨╡╤В╤А╨╛╨▓ ╨Я╨╡╤В╤А                   140     8       1120

Answer (score 1):

*Пуск*->*Выполнить*->*regedit*

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\Autorun
```

Изменить значение на *chcp 65001*

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 0):

Выполнил все как в источнике тут http://larakit.ru/blog/php-dev-workplace/25.html, заработало.
Стандартная консоль (cmd) из OpenServer сразу заработал.

Аттачем прикрепил измененную конфигу для git-bash так же из OpenServer

[image: Конфигурация Locale для git-bash (Если запускать из меню OpenServer)]